# Sql in bash script (postgres)

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, variables

i have a command in bash script for rename base.
It's work, example

> psql -U $User -t -A -q -c 'ALTER DATABASE "Old_Name" RENAME TO "New_Name"'

But if i do this -

> O_Name='Old_Name'

> N_Name='New_Name'

> psql -U $User -t -A -q -c 'ALTER DATABASE "$O_Name" RENAME TO "$N_Name"'

It's not work, i think sql get $O_Name not Old_Name.
How to pass the value of a variable bash to sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes don't allow for environment variable expansion. Use double quotes instead (and escape the nested quotes). Like,

```
psql -U $User -t -A -q -c "ALTER DATABASE \"$O_Name\" RENAME TO \"$N_Name\""
```

Comment: it's work i think, but i get ERROR: Column "Old_Name" does not exist in 
> psql -U $UserDB -t -A -q -c "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid() AND datname = \"$Old_Name\""
I think it's normal, remove all connections and rename base. Rename work.

Comment: But why it's call "error" not "warning". Don't understand.
Thank you. :)

Comment: It's hard to tell, but if you renamed the database then you should get an error testing for the old name - since the old name does not exist anymore.

Comment: Find AND datname = \"$Old_Name\"" need send datname = 'MyName' with '.

psql -U $UserDB -t -A -q -c "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid() AND datname = '$Old_Name'"
This work)